# Is active waiting common in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am in a debate with a colleague that it is bad programming if you do active waiting in Linux.

He is more experienced than I am in bash scripting and says it is common to do it.

For example, we try to start a bash script after a WiFi USB is inserted.
He will look up every minute if one is here.
I will take the USB event and when it's WiFi, start my script with that device.

Please help us with that question.

Comment: "Common" and "bad" are not mutually exclusive. You have to poll if that is the only option available to you.

Comment: From my point of view it is bad, when you will say its common than it will not be good for me. If you say it is common and bad I am sad. If its not common and good also. So I will still work on m$

Comment: I think it's bad, but how bad is it? Is it bad enough to spend the time to rewrite the script? Would the new script's inner working be common enough to be maintained by someone else than you? Sometimes the most simple solutions are the best, even if they're far from the most efficient.

Comment: If you want to convince your colleague, you might want to rewrite the script (on your own time?) and show him the new version, prove him it works the same in a more efficient fashion and that it is still easy to maintain.

Comment: Only he and I will work on it. We talked about how to go on. so no work is done yet

Comment: Then maybe you can convince him to let you work on this part, making sure it won't impact other parts he can deal with in the meantime. And of course explain him the whole thing afterward

Comment: Make sure you're certain that it won't take 10 times as long to write and test though, or be willing to give up that implementation if you find out there are more problems than you initially thought

Comment: hmm ok I also do Quick and Dirty programming, but only for proof of concepts. I always try to be in the programming guidelines. And bash is learning by doing for me and I have no guidelines so I asked you if jobs are done in this way.

Comment: I'm not too sure myself, I don't often write waits and the last ones I did where done with `while` + `sleep`. I think there are more efficient solutions, but I also think they require much more code and I haven't looked further into it. Maybe there's an utility that makes it easy, but I don't know it. StackOverflow isn't the best pick for this kind of question btw ("how can I implement X"), but you might have better chances on the [Unix&Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: BTW, if this is for a system using systemd-networkd, you may find [networkd-dispatcher](https://github.com/craftyguy/networkd-dispatcher) (as a means to invoke your script when network devices attach/detach/are configured/etc) to be of interest or use.

Answer (score 2):

As somebody already mentioned, common and bad aren't exclusive. So let's just look at the **advantages** and **disadvantages:**

It sounds like what you're doing is basically *event-driven* or *reactive* "programming", whereas your colleague is advocating for a polling approach.

The **advantage** of reactive programming is that something happens exactly when it should, i.e. when the usb stick is inserted. The **disadvantage** is that the system needs to support this, i.e. some hook must be provided to fire off your script.

This means that polling approaches are usually **more widely applicable and portable**, but they are, by definition, (almost) **always a little late**. If that is not a concern, then the polling approach can be advantageous, because of its aforementioned portability.

With your specific USB thing, it sounds like you already figured out how to hook your script into the udev system. Personally, I'd say that's the way to go. Else you'd either wait up to a minute for your script to figure out that something was plugged in, or you increase the polling cadence, wasting more and more cpu cycles (even though nowadays, `sleep`ing is not so expensive anymore.)

Answer (score 1):

Periodic polling is often unavoidable and is quite common. It is called active waiting when it consumes too much cpu, because the period is small and/or the polling code is heavy. The problem of long period is that it reduces the reactivity.

You should also take into account that avoiding periodic polling may require more complex code, harder to maintain.

Comment: That's a matter of using the right tools. In terms of waiting for a USB device to attach, for instance, the conventional approach is to use udev rules -- in which case the script is called when the device attaches, so there's no need to poll at all. Likewise, waiting for a file to create, one can and should use `incron`, which will call your script when that file is created or closed; in both cases, the extra complexity is moved into the tool, and isn't part of your script.

Comment: ...I'd also argue that polling is more prone to race conditions. If you're just looking for files, you can get called at any time after the file is created, including before its contents have been fully written; if you're called via an event that triggers only when the file is *closed* after having been written, then you know it's complete. Likewise, waiting for devices to be attached, you have more control over exactly when you're invoked if you tell udevd to trigger on a given kind of signal (add vs. change for example).

Comment: Imagine the software of a photo printing kiosk. It will ask the client to plug its usb key and wait until it is ready. I think a polling is more simple in this case. For all the cases where root access is not given to developers, modification of udev rules requires a lot of administrative workload.

Comment: if you're developing a photo printing kiosk, you'd damned well better have root access -- how else are you going to harden the thing? Yes, the code you eventually call after an event takes place shouldn't have root, but to develop an embedded device without letting your developers build and test OS-level integration is silly -- you're paying in user experience (higher latency), and gaining... *what*?

Comment: (My day job is lead for a team building the software stack for a piece of hardware sold as an appliance; this is an area I have no small amount of firsthand experience in, and a rather substantial set of opinions drawn therefrom / backed thereby).

Comment: ...which is to say: The team building the software stack for a kiosk is rightly responsible for everything from the way the bootloader's integrity is verified to the way updates are signed and installed to how privilege separation is maintained between processes and how code processing untrusted data is isolated from the rest of the system. If you're responsible for, say, setting up a syscall filter so that the code parsing uploaded images can't be attacked via a bug in the library you're using, there's *no possible way* you can do that work without privileged access during design and test.

Comment: That active waiting is only when it consums too much cpu, I have never heard. But ok for a task like this its more easier to look every minute for wifi usb dongle and is not too much for cpu.

On the other side I will try to use the udev rules, in worst case I do not have to wait 59sec until the script is started.